# full page scroll based based on mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do the one page scroll based on the mousewheel. On mouse down, the section below moves up and on the mouse up, the section above moves down. There are five sections and I am using variable 'a' with initial value as 1, on mousedown *a* increments and sends the value as id of the section (eg:a=2, `document.getElementbyId(a)` should call the section 2). This is expected result.

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<style>
 section { height: 100vh;
 border:1px solid black; }
 .pushupsections{
     margin-bottom:-100vh;
 }   
</style>
</head>

<body>
<section id=1>1</section> 
<section id="2">2</section>
<section id="3">3</section>
<section id="4">4</section>
<section id="5">5</section>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var a=1;
 $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
// var e;
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        // alert(1);
        if(a>1){               
        a--;

         //$(a).addClass("pushupsections");
        // document.getElementById( a ).addclass("pushupsections");
        }
     }
    else{          
        if(a<5){
        a++;

            //   document.getElementById( a ).addclass("pushupsections");
            }        
    }
});
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead. 
The most complete and popular library for that kind of effect.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the sections's width and height to `100%` and set their positions to `fixed`. For the section's container set `overflow: hidden`.

Here is the implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/f9ug3wv5/

Comment: thank you for the solution.but the effect i was looking is as in www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.htm